# Input/output error in OS X but not Linux on NTFS external hard drive

Tags: linux, macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs

My external hard drive contains a directory. On my Mac I can't see this folder, neither in Finder nor with `ls -la`. But I know that it exists, since there is no problem with it on Linux. Because I'm sure about its existence, I tried the following:

```
[1] .:[ manuelschneider@mbp13 ]:. /Volumes/Caviar $ cd Video
-bash: cd: Video: Input/output error
```

What is the problem? The drive is an external USB drive with NTFS.

Comment: Are you sure your disk has been mounted? If it has not, for any reason, then you could not see it. Try looking at the output of *fdisk*. Also, try to see whether it is listed among USB devices, whether mounted or not, with the command *system_profiler SPUSBDataType*

Comment: For best results, put into your question _exactly_ what steps you took when removing your hard disc from your Linux machine.

Comment: /Volumes/Caviar is the mounted HDD. The device was properly unmounted on linux.

Comment: Exact same problem with an external NTFS drive.. unable to find an answer.

Answer (score -1):

MacOS has very poor support for NTFS drives. For example it is not able to write to such drives.

I suppose this is just one more symptom of this disability.
But this issue occurs on only one particular folder, right? I guess this folder is might be owned by some user or it has permissions that are not handlebar for macOS.